# regex get anything between double curly braces

Tags: .net, regex

I need to get the text between double curly braces in .NET. 
I got this:

```
\{{([^}]+)\}}
```

However, it also includes the double curly braces. 
Is there a way to exclude them?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm no master of regex, but this ought to work and answers your question about exclusively selecting elements before and after. Try:

```
(?<=\{\{).*?(?=\}\})
```

If you'd like an explanation as to why this works, I'll walk you through it: 
`(?<=\{\{)` is the start of a *positive lookbehind**, which matches a group after what you're looking for without including it in the result. This is basically the first part of what you asked for. The `\{\{)` are the escaped characters you're actually looking for.

`.*?` is saying you'd like to select anything any amount of times (but as few as possible) until you get to the group `(?=\}\})` which is a *positive lookahead*, essentially the second part of what you're looking for. This selects everything behind that selector, the two escaped end curly braces, without selecting the braces themselves.

Comment: Be careful. The positive lookbehind will break your apps in Safari as of Version 15.2 (17612.3.6.1.6)

Answer (score 2):

Groups[0] is whole substring

Groups[1] and so on returns text between ()

Try

```
new Regex(@"\{{([^}]+)\}}").Match("dfdf{{456gfd}}3453").Groups[1]
```

Answer (score 2):

*(This answer is not specific to .NET)*

For a basic capturing regexp that is non-greedy (and so will match the smallest string sourrounded by double quotes) and including text enclosed in single curly braces in the match:

```
{{(([^}][^}]?|[^}]}?)*)}}
```

### Example

Given

```
{{first group}} nothing {{second {special} group}}
```

We will come away with the following captures

- `first Group`
- `second {special} group`

### Explanation

- `{{` :: Matches the opening double braces
- `(`...`)` :: Our desired position capture

  - `(...|...)*` :: Matches repeated occurrences of either of the two
    alternatives separated by the `|`

    - `[^}][^}]?` :: Matches anything that is not the closing double braces,
      `}}` (the `?` is necessary to ensure we can match odd and even length
      strings)
    - `[^}]}?` :: Matches an optional single closing brace that is no
      preceded directly with a prior brace.
- `}}` :: Matches the closing double braces

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but I tested this in https://regex101.com/ and except for java8, this seems to work:

```
({{.*?}})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = "This is a {{sample}} string with {{double}} curly braces.";

string pattern = @"\{\{(.*?)\}\}";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    string content = match.Groups[0].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Content with braces: " + content);

    string content2 = match.Groups[1].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("Content without braces: " + content2);
}
```